# What counter-measures for cheating exist?

Tags: strategy

Given how huge an advantage real-time external feedback to a player during championship games would give the player, do any of the major chess championships deploy counter-measures to prevent the same sort of cheats you might expect to find at a casino? If so, are these counter-measures well known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, [Cheating in Chess](http://www.chessbase.com/columns/column.asp?pid=190), by Frederic Friedel.

**Abstract**

> Nowadays, players at all levels of chess can profit from computer
>   assistance during a game. This is a new development and a serious
>   problem for the game. This contribution lists the main forms of
>   cheating and provides some occurrences from practice. The most
>   prevailing one (Allwermann at the Böblinger Open) is placed in a
>   historical context by describing previously noticed cases of cheating.
>   Finally, the problem of cheating is addressed at the highest level of
>   play. What are the possibilities and how can we prevent cheating at
>   this level? Since there is no clear solution, the issue of cheating
>   remains on the list of issues to be addressed very seriously in the
>   near future.

Comment: Oh, that's cool.  Did you do that yourself, or is there a facility to insert the abstract automagically?

Comment: @blunders - thanks. I understand editing and comments.  I was just wondering if adding "Abstract" the way you did automatically snagged some text from the link.  Anyway, I didn't know the bare links weren't permitted, so thanks for that info.  I'll dress them up more in the future.

Answer (score 5):

There have been tournaments that require the players pass through a metal detector, and play in an isolated environment with no spectator contact.  Still, there was the whole [Toiletgate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2006) incident during the 2006 Topalov-Kramnik match, so even these measures might not seem like 'enough.'  Besides resorting to strip searching the players, what else can be done except isolate them from the outside world during the games?